# Return Set from Lua Script

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, lua

Lua Script:

```
local r = {}

for _, m in pairs(ARGV) do
    if redis.call('SISMEMBER', KEYS[1], m) == 1 then
        r[#r + 1] = m
    end
end
return r
```

I am using redis-templete of sprint boot

```
@Autowired
private RedisScript<Set> redisScript;

Set<String> set = redisTemplete.execute(redisScript,"a", Arrays.asList("1", "2")); --to execute redis lua scipt 

Above redisTemplete.execute command not working error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set

It works when I use assign result to List instead of Set    List<String> set = redisTemplete.execute(redisScript, "a", Arrays.asList("1", "2")); --working
```

Is there any way to modify Lua script so that it returns set instead of List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/script/RedisScript.html

> Interface RedisScript<T>
>
> Type Parameters:
> T - The script result type.
> Should be one of Long, Boolean, List, or deserialized value type. Can be null if the script returns a
> throw-away status (i.e "OK")

So your redis script should not have type Set in the first place.

execute will return that type. So if you want a Set you probably convert your List into a Set on the Java side.

From https://redis.io/commands/eval

> Note: as you can see Lua arrays are returned as Redis multi bulk
> replies, that is a Redis return type that your client library will
> likely convert into an Array type in your programming language.

While you can implement sets in Lua using tables I don't think there is a way to get that set through your API as it will be converted to a multi bulk reply which is then converted to a List.